# Export calender in exchange to ICS file for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, outlook, exchange-server

I'm trying to display calender events in Wordpress that originate on an exchange server. Wordpress accepts an ICS file.

How can I get an ICS file from MS Exchange Email Server?

note: It doesn't have to be an ics filer pre se, as long as there is a way to import into wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect with Exchange Web Services (EWS) with some custom code, you can get appointment details and format them into an ICS file to push to WordPress.

Comment: which web service gets calender data?

Comment: Did you review the documentation at all? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877049(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: Thanks Brian. I must have missed that.